# Encode file as base64 and send to API

Tags: python, json, api

I'm currently having issues sending a file to an API.  I've manually tested my scripts base64 output by printing to the screen and copying and pasting this directly into the API's sandbox which works correctly but when I package it up in JSON ready to send, it no longer works.

What I need is this to send to the API:

```
{
  "content": "mybase64encodedfilestuff"
}
```

and my python code is:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
encoded_string = encoded_string.decode("utf-8")
payload = {}
payload['content'] = encoded_string
json_payload = json.dumps(payload)
```

I then send this to the API as:

```
r =  requests.post(url='https://api.example.com/uploads', data=payload,
                   headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Authorization': 'Basic '+api_string}, timeout=5)
```

I feel like I've missed something simple but can't figure it out as I just get a error 400, please provide valid content first.  If I make the payload a copy and paste of the print output it works.

Comment: You're creating a `json_payload` variable but sending `payload`. Is that what you mean to do?

Comment: Thanks Pedro :-) Sometimes one can't see for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd converted my string to a JSON but they used the original string, not the JSONified one.